# Can't install node.js on Linux server

Tags: linux, node.js, debian

I followed some instructions to install node.js on a Linux server and ran in to the following blocks. I started out by doing `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties` and that worked fine. Then, I did `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js`. But, wait - there is no command `add-apt-repository`. OK, so I looked it up and it told me to do  `apt-get install software-properties-common` and that would have been fine, except it gave me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
```

Well, what can I do to get node.js on my server? Obviously, none of this works and it's Debian, in case you were wondering. I really need help on this. Basically, how can I install `software-properties-common` if it does not exist? It just won't show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a Debian install of the latest node.js, you should follow [these instructions](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager), not requiring you to add the PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install python g++ make checkinstall
mkdir ~/src && cd $_
wget -N http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz
tar xzvf node-latest.tar.gz && cd node-v*
./configure
checkinstall #(remove the "v" in front of the version number in the dialog)
sudo dpkg -i node_*
```

**UPDATE:** I wrote this a long time ago. Since then, I find using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) a much less painful way to get node onto machines. As per link, steps are basically reduced to:

- `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash`
- `nvm install node`

Comment: for anybody else viewing this, the next steps would be make, sudo make install, and then node -v to see the version

Comment: I have tried this a few different times, and either checkinstall throws an error or node does when running it. I am attempting this on a fresh install of debian 7.1 in virtualbox